# How to duplicate command line curl command with Visual C++ libcurl

Tags: c++, libcurl

I've been using libcurl in my Visual C++ programs for a while. I'm trying to write a new program that duplicates this command line:

> curl -d 'assetclass=1&viewall=1&action=Go' https://stockmarketmba.com/stockscreener.php

This is the first time that I've had to 'click' on buttons to get the data that I want. This is my code, minus the code that checks the returns of the `curl_easy_setopt()` calls:

```
static size_t WriteCallBack( void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp ) noexcept {     

  size_t nbytes( size * nmemb );
  ((std::string*)userp)->append( (char*)contents, nbytes );
  return nbytes;

}

ReadWebData() {

  CURLcode res;
  string bufr;

  CURL *handle = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://stockmarketmba.com/stockscreener.php" );

  char const *postfields = { "assetclass=1&viewall=1&action=Go" };
  curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postfields );
  curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)strlen( postfields ) );

  curl_easy_setopt( this->handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallBack );
  curl_easy_setopt( this->handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &bufr )

  res = curl_easy_perform( handle );

  if ( res == CURLE_OK ) {
    // process data in bufr here
  }
}
```

When I look in `bufr`, it contains the same data that I got before I added the `curl_easy_setopt()` calls with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE`. I added `curl_easy_setopt()` calls with `CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION`, `CURLOPT_DEBUGDATA`, and `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`, and don't see where the post fields are sent to the server.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are using the **local variable** `handle` for most of the libcurl calls, except for the 2 calls that set `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` and `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`, where you are using the **class member** `this->handle` instead. So the call to `curl_easy_perform()` will not invoke your `WriteCallback()` to write any data to `bufr`

Comment: I'm guessing that's just a typo in the example but please provide a [mre] that you've compiled and tested that reproduces your problem